# VersionOne Usage

Tags: c#, versionone

I'm new to VersionOne usage. I have downloaded the dll's of VersionOne API client and 'am trying to use to get following agile metrics. I'm trying to write a sample .Net application which should be able to pull data from the hosted version one site. I have read few blogs and came to know that VersionOne supports cross language API integration. But, currently I'm stuck in getting the following details to start with.

Can anyone please help me in this regard.

- How to get the list of projects under "Programs" using V1Instance class?
- How to get the list of all stories?
- How to get data to create burn charts?

Consider the VersionOne is hosted in this website: 
https://v1.com/v1/..

Also can you please suggest any website where I can get enough information for using versionone api's to retrive data.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you have an example of some code you have tried or places you have looked for docs?

Comment: Hi @jamesj, 
Yes "https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.NET.ObjectModel" is the place where I started the research. Can you please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical piece of information is that ScopeLabel is what you see as Program in the VersionOne UI. Without that knowledge, you'll search all over the developer docs and source code and you won't find what you need.

Armed with that, you would discover that ScopeLabel is not in the SDK.NET Object Model. Moreover, for the uses you are describing (like getting data for a burndown chart), you should not use the Object Model. It was designed for fine-grained access like reading and writing individual Stories. Due to the [Fallacies of Distributed Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing), it performs very poorly for course-grained reporting needs.

A better starting point is the documentation on [API Query for Burndown Data](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/API_Query_for_Burndown_data). You can also find some sample source code in the [VersionOne OAuth2 Sample Clients](https://github.com/versionone/versionone-oauth2-examples) on GitHub, specifically see the [CSharp YamlClient](https://github.com/versionone/versionone-oauth2-examples/blob/master/csharp/YamlClient/Program.cs). By no means is it a finished application, but it will be a much better starting point.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Can you please share me a sample query to get to know the "total number of stories accepted". I was able to get a basic understanding on how to get query for particular member in the version one system using the following sample query - "https://v1.com/v1/rest-1.v1/data/member/20".

Can you please share me a sample query as shown above for getting to know the projects listed under a program.

Comment: I got it. I used the scopelabel concept in REST based query to get to know a program detail in VersionOne system. 

For ex - <v1_serverurl>/<v1_application_name>/rest-1.v1/data/scopelabel/10

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look through the code in [here](https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.NET.ObjectModel/blob/master/ObjectModel/V1Instance.cs). For example a quick search turned up using the `Projects` property on V1Instance to get projects, the `projects.GetStories` method on Project to get the list of stories.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. One clarification is where "GetStories()" method is defined. As I was not able to find it in the code shared. Please help.

Comment: in Project.cs. The Projects property on V1Instance returns an IEnumerable of Project objects. eg. foreach(var project in instance.Projects) { var stories = project.GetStories(...); //.... }

Comment: Thanks James. But in my current application, there are no projects listed and hence instance of V1Instance class > "instance.Projects" returns 0. But I'm able to view projects under "Programs" section in the VersionOne website. So, can you please suggest me on how to query the "Programs" section using VersionOne .Net client API.